# Button height to row height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hi I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I have this piece of code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button>Öğrenci Projeleri</button></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button>İş Projeleri</button></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button>Grafik Tasarım</button></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button>Üniversite Başvuruları</button></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button>Danışmanlık</button></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2"><button>&Fazlası</button></div>
</div>
```

the button heights are equal however the button heights are not equal to row height, what I'm trying to say is that there are gaps between the buttons and top/bottom of the row.

if I increase the buttonheight the row height increases correspondingly

how can I remove the gaps or increase the button height without increasing the row height? I want the button top and bottom borders to touch row top and bottom

Thanks

Comment: There must be something else in your custom css which could be causing this, padding and/or margin. Otherwise, out-of-the-box there is no such issue. See this quick fiddle to demonstrate that -- http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/svx9w0L1/

Comment: (*offtopic*) Was any of this and other answers (on the previous questions you asked) helpful? If you vote/accept answers or even participate in comments might help future visitors with a similar problem to easily spot the solution. Also if you have a solution on your own issue, feel free to write your answer and mark it as accepted. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0):

normally btn class (the base class of buttons bootstrap) has margins or paddings like this

```
.btn {
     -moz-user-select: none;
     background-image: none;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     border-radius: 4px;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: normal;
     line-height: 1.42857;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     padding: 10px 15px;    /* this margin */
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

you can avoid redefining class locallmente or in your own version of bootstrap or intervening specificatamento for single button by assigning a style that changes the general settings eg:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus" 
       href="yourRef" 
       style="padding: 3px 2px;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined any Bootstrap class for your buttons ie `.btn`. You also may want to use a [button group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) as trying to fit buttons inside columns doesn't work to well generally. (*The red background denotes the `row`.)

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
div.row {
  background-color: red;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  div.btn-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn,
  div.btn-group > .btn {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn,
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group,
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group > .btn {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group > .btn {
    float: none;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn + .btn,
  div.btn-vertical > .btn +.btn-group,
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group + .btn,
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group + .btn-group {
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn:first-child:not(:last-child) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn:last-child:not(:first-child) {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  }
  .btn-vertical > .btn-group:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) > .btn {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group:first-child:not(:last-child) > .btn:last-child,
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group:first-child:not(:last-child) > .dropdown-toggle {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  }
  div.btn-vertical > .btn-group:last-child:not(:first-child) > .btn:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
  }
}
div.btn-group.btn-group-lg .btn,
div.btn-group .btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Standard Button Group.</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Öğrenci Projeleri</button>
      <button class="btn btn-warning">İş Projeleri</button>
      <button class="btn btn-default">Grafik Tasarım</button>
      <button class="btn btn-danger">Üniversite Başvuruları</button>
      <button class="btn btn-success">Danışmanlık</button>
      <button class="btn">&amp; Fazlası</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Justfied Button Group.</h3>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Öğrenci Projeleri</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-warning">İş Projeleri</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-default">Grafik Tasarım</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Üniversite Başvuruları</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Danışmanlık</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button class="btn">&amp; Fazlası</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="media-change">
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Custom Button Groups</h2> 
    <p>These will change from Horizontal to Vertical at a breakpoint for Mobile.</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="btn-group btn-vertical" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Öğrenci Projeleri</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning">İş Projeleri</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default">Grafik Tasarım</button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Üniversite Başvuruları</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Danışmanlık</button>
        <button class="btn">&amp; Fazlası</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="media-change">
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Custom Justfied Button Group.</h3>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified btn-vertical">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Öğrenci Projeleri</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">İş Projeleri</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-default">Grafik Tasarım</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Üniversite Başvuruları</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Danışmanlık</button>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button class="btn">&amp; Fazlası</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```